# SQL MAX date without group by

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following table

```
Location Type     Date
A        TestType 10-10-2013
A        TestType 05-05-2013
A        BestType 06-06-2013
B        TestType 09-09-2013
B        TestType 01-01-2013
```

I want to return the max date for each location regardless of the type but I must return all 3 columns.

Desired result:

```
Location Type     Date
A        TestType 10-10-2013
B        TestType 09-09-2013
```

What would be the best way to do this?

I've looked into using `RANK() Over Partition`, but can't get it to work properly.

Comment: Why don't you want to use group by?

Comment: I must return the Type column as well so grouping becomes awkward

Comment: `I must return the Type column` Which of them?

Comment: Why not just `ORDER BY Date DESC` which you could combine with `SELECT TOP 1`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `row_number()` function *and* `partition by location ordering by [date] desc` *to get the* `max date` for each location.

```
;with cte as (
   select location, type, [date], 
          row_number() over (partition by location order by [date] desc) rn
   from yourTable
)
select location, type, [date]
from cte
where rn = 1 --<<-- rn = 1 gets the max date for each location.
```

**[Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/19535/1)**

Comment: This looks like it's doing the job. Will double check the results with what's in the database and update

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
SELECT location, MAX(date)
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY location;
```

EDIT:

If you want to get type with it you can do:

```
select y.location, y.Type, y.date
from YourTable y
inner join(
    select location, max(date) maxdate
    from YourTable
    group by location
) ss on y.location = ss.location and y.date = ss.maxdate
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d7f7e/2)</kbd>

Comment: I updated my answer, but this isn't fullproof. If you have the same date for the same location, it will return it two times. You can use DISTINCT on that case, but if they have different types, it will still return two. It looks like @Kaf's version handles this better than my answer.