# Is it possible to write this query without group by

Tags: sql, group-by

```
select  MAX(date), TypeId, DirectionId
from mqview.[Message]
where RecActive = 1
group by TypeId, DirectionId
```

DirectionId contains only values 1 (I - input) and 2 (O - output). TypeId contains for now 10 types. DirectionId and typeId are foreign keys to their codelists. Table message currently containts > 3.6 millions records. I added proper index which executes upper query ~1.5 seconds, but I want it to be faster. Index definition:

```
create index covering_index ON [mqview].[Message] (TypeId, DirectionId, [Date] desc)
```

Executing for each TypeId is fast (only traversing index tree).

```
select top 1 * from mqview.Message where RecActive = 1 and TypeId = 2 and DirectionId = 1 order by id desc
```

But Type codelist contains 10 types, so this makes 20 queries (Direction makes it times 2). I figured group by makes the most latency. Is there a way to rewrite it without group by?

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2014.

**UPDATE**

Query I'm using to get results is actually now like this:

```
select m.Date as 'Date', t.Code as 'Type', d.Code as 'Direction'
from
  mqview.Message m
  inner join mqview.MessageType t on (t.id = m.TypeId)
  inner join mqview.MessageDirection d on (d.Id = m.DirectionId)
where
  t.Visible = 1
  and m.Id in (
                      SELECT
                        MAX(Id)
                      FROM
                        mqview.[Message]
                      where
                        RecActive = 1 and Date is not null
                      GROUP BY
                        TypeId,
                         DirectionId
                        )
```

After adding index sugested by Gordon Linoff (slighly different), the query now executes ~1s.

```
create index covering_index ON [mqview].[Message] (RecActive, Date desc, TypeId, DirectionId,) include (id);
```

I'm not sure if `include(id)` is needed. Without the `include(id)` the index points to RowID (which points to table row), with `include(id)` index stores Id (therefore covering index), but running query without `include` (dropped index, created new one) makes no time difference.

Comment: What flavour of sql are you using?

Comment: Yes, using a correlated sub-query. But it will most probably be even slower.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: There are other ways but not optimized or efficient than above.

Comment: what about using partition by ???

Comment: Added sql flavour to question (mssql 2014).

Answer (score 2):

If I had to speculate, the issue is the `where` clause.  Try creating an index that includes that clause:

```
create index covering_index ON [mqview].[Message] (RecActive, TypeId, DirectionId, [Date] desc) ;
```

Or, so the existing index is used better, switch to conditional aggregation:

```
select  max(case when RecActive = 1 then date end), TypeId, DirectionId
from mqview.[Message]
group by TypeId, DirectionId;
```

When you do the query for each type independently, the conditions on type and direction and in the `where` clause, with all clauses having equality comparisons connected by `and`s.  Hence the optimizer can use the existing index, looking up `RecActive` in the data pages.

The answer to your question is that there are other ways to write the query, but they may have the same problem without the right index.  One idea is to use a correlated subquery:

```
select m.*
from mqview.[Message] m
where m.RecActive = 1 and
      m.date = (select max(m2.date)
                from mqview.[Message] m2
                where m2.RecActive = 1 and m2.typeid = m.typeid and m2.directionid = m.directionid
               );
```

If you have a list of the types and directions:

```
select t.typeid, d.directionid, m.date
from types t cross join
     dimensions d cross apply
     (select top 1 m.date
      from mqview.[Message] m
      where m.typeid = t.typeid and m.directionid = d.directionid and
            RecActive = 1
      order by date desc
     ) m;
```

Comment: smart to DESC on the date.... this could also be solved with CTE http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19771780/sql-max-date-without-group-by

Comment: Correlated subquery has similar or maybe a little more time of execution. But thanks for the alternative.

Answer (score 0):

I think partition would be faster with proper index. Try this

```
; WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT IIF(RecActive = 1, date, ''), TypeID, DirectionId, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TypeID, DirectionID ORDER BY date DESC)
    FROM mqview.[Message]
)
SELECT * FROM CTE CTE 
WHERE CTE.RN = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select max.date, T.* from 
(select distinct TypeId, DirectionId from mqview.[Message] where RecActive = 1) T
outer apply (select top 1 date from mqview.[Message] where RecActive = 1 and T.TypeID = TypeID and T.DirectionId = DirectionID order by date desc ) max
```